# Neo4j 2.3.1 Server dies when saving SDN4 Entity with multiple relationships

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm writing an application for a guide service and I'm running a 3 server cluster of Neo4j 2.3.1 on digital ocean droplets.  I'm also using Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE from a JSF web app running under Tomcat to write and query my data.

I have a node with potentially 7 different relationships to other nodes that I have successfully saved 80+ instances of but I suddenly started getting Out of memory errors on the instance 1 master neo4j server when I would try to save the node.  I updated the memory settings for the Neo4j server to the following :

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=512
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
```

I no longer get the OutOfMemoryError but now the server fails when I try to save the node.  I can query data prior to the server failing fine.  I never get an error message in the server 1 master data/log/console.log file but in the Server 2 slave data/log/console.log file I get the following message :

```
2015-12-31 15:42:00.405-0500 INFO  Instance 1  is alive
2015-12-31 15:42:00.539-0500 INFO  Instance 1  was elected as coordinator
2015-12-31 15:42:00.598-0500 INFO  Instance 1  is available as master at ha://0.0.0.0:6001?serverId=1 with StoreId{creationTime=1447860597504, randomId=2820629596580485150, storeVersion=15250506225055238, upgradeTime=1447860597504, upgradeId=1}
2015-12-31 15:42:00.647-0500 INFO  Instance 1  is available as backup at backup://127.0.0.1:6362 with StoreId{creationTime=1447860597504, randomId=2820629596580485150, storeVersion=15250506225055238, upgradeTime=1447860597504, upgradeId=1}
2015-12-31 15:42:11.652-0500 INFO  Instance 1  has failed
```

The Node Entity Java code :

```
public class OutfitterWaterfowlHunt extends WaterfowlHunt {

    @Relationship(type="RUN_BY", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private GuideService guideService;

    @Relationship(type="GUIDED", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Guide> fieldStaffHunter = new ArrayList<Guide>();

    @Relationship(type="ASSIGNED_BY", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Guide fieldStaff;

    public void addGuide(Guide guide)
    {
        this.fieldStaffHunter.add(guide);
    }

    public List<Guide> getFieldStaffHunter() {
        return fieldStaffHunter;
    }

    public void setFieldStaffHunter(List<Guide> fieldStaffHunter) {
        this.fieldStaffHunter = fieldStaffHunter;
    }

    public GuideService getGuideService() {
        return guideService;
    }

    public void setGuideService(GuideService guideService) {
        this.guideService = guideService;
    }

    public Guide getFieldStaff() {
        return fieldStaff;
    }

    public void setFieldStaff(Guide fieldStaff) {
        this.fieldStaff = fieldStaff;
    }   
}



public class WaterfowlHunt extends Excursion {

    @Property(name="type")
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }   
}


public class Excursion extends BaseEntity {

    @Relationship(type="OCCURED_ON", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private TookPlaceOn occuredOn;

    @Relationship(type="OCCURED_AT", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private ExcursionLocation excursionLocation;

    @Relationship(type="PARTICIPATED_IN", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
    private HuntGroupRole participatedIn;

    @Relationship(type="HARVESTED", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private HuntInformation harvestInfo;


    public TookPlaceOn occuredOn(Day day, Long timeIn, Long timeOut)
    {
        TookPlaceOn tpo = new TookPlaceOn();

        tpo.setDayOfExcursion(day);
        tpo.setExcursion(this);

        tpo.setTimeIn(timeIn);
        tpo.setTimeOut(timeOut);

        this.occuredOn = tpo;

        day.addOccuredOn(tpo);

        return tpo;
    }

    public void occuredAt(ExcursionLocation huntLocation)
    {
        this.setExcursionLocation(huntLocation);
    }

    public void harvested(HuntInformation harvestInfo)
    {
        this.setHarvestInfo(harvestInfo);
    }

    public HuntGroupRole participatedIn(HuntGroup huntGroup, Integer         nbrOfHunters)
    {
        HuntGroupRole hgr = new HuntGroupRole();

        hgr.setHuntGroup(huntGroup);
        hgr.setHuntingSpot(this);

        hgr.setNumberOfHunters(nbrOfHunters);

        this.participatedIn = hgr;

        huntGroup.addParticipatedIn(hgr);

        return hgr;
    }

    public HuntGroupRole getParticipatedIn() {
        return participatedIn;
    }

    public void setParticipatedIn(HuntGroupRole participatedIn) {
        this.participatedIn = participatedIn;
    }

    public TookPlaceOn getOccuredOn() {
        return occuredOn;
    }

    public void setOccuredOn(TookPlaceOn occuredOn) {
        this.occuredOn = occuredOn;
    }

    public ExcursionLocation getExcursionLocation() {
        return excursionLocation;
    }

    public void setExcursionLocation(ExcursionLocation excursionLocation) {
        this.excursionLocation = excursionLocation;
    }

    public HuntInformation getHarvestInfo() {
        return harvestInfo;
    }

    public void setHarvestInfo(HuntInformation harvestInfo) {
        this.harvestInfo = harvestInfo;
    }

}
```

The code I use to save is through a SDN4 GraphRepository save:

```
    @Transactional
    public void saveHunt() 
    {        
        OutfitterWaterfowlHunt owh = new OutfitterWaterfowlHunt();

        owh.setType("GuideTypeHere");

        Day doh = this.determineDayOfHunt();

        owh.occuredOn(doh, this.timeIn.getTime(), this.timeOut.getTime());
        owh.participatedIn(this.huntGroup, this.nbrOfHunters);

        GuideService gs = WDSSession.getInstance().getNeo4JController().retrieveGuideServiceByName("GuideServiceNameHere");

        owh.setGuideService(gs);
        owh.setFieldStaffHunter(this.selectedFSMembers);
        owh.setFieldStaff(this.responsibleFieldStaffer);
        owh.occuredAt(this.huntLocation);

        HuntInformation hi = this.populateHuntInformation();

        owh.setHarvestInfo(hi);

        owh = WDSSession.getInstance().getNeo4JController().saveOutfitterWaterfowlHunt(owh);

        StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
        msg.append("Successfully Saved Hunt ");
        msg.append(" (");
        msg.append(owh.getGraphId());
        msg.append(").");

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Hunt Save Status", msg.toString()));
    }
```

GraphRepository save  :

```
    @Transactional
    public OutfitterWaterfowlHunt saveOutfitterWaterfowlHunt(OutfitterWaterfowlHunt owh)
    {
        OutfitterWaterfowlHunt owHunt = this.outWtrFwlRepo.save(owh);

        return owHunt;
    }
```

Any ideas on what is causing the server to suddenly start failing when saving this node?  I currently have 19957 nodes in my Neo4j db of which most make up my DateTree.  Is there a better way to save the Node than what I'm currently doing?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the yet-to-be-released neo4j-ogm 2.0. The hard way to fix this in the meantime is to save all related entities first and then the top level entity, but looking at your model, this isn't straightforward.

Comment: Is there an estimated release date for the ogm 2.0?  I'll try saving the related nodes like you suggested and let you know if that fixes my problems for now.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess in a fortnight but don't hold me to it :-)

Comment: Thanks Luanne!  I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @wwixon An OGM 2.0 snapshot is now available - please use the docs for the OGM http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ . The docs for SDN 4.1 are not updated yet, but please follow what Vince has described here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758072/neo4jserver-in-neo4jconfiguration-4-1-0. You may need to include  <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>